# How do you use tokenize_tagline to retrieve tags of html in Ruby using Watir toolkit

Tags: ruby, arrays, xpath, watir, tokenize

I have an HTML element:

```
<iframe marginheight=0 marginwidth=0 frameborder=0 height=100 width=400 src="/website/authorisation.jsp?a=f556">
    </iframe>
```

I want to retrieve the code src of the element. How does one do that please? I have been looking around and the only answer I see is to tokenize the element but there is no mention of how you use the tokenizer.

Comment: What do you need? HTML of iframe tag, or HTML of the website/authorisation.jsp?a=f556 page?

Comment: I want it to return "/website/authorisation.jsp?a=f556" so whatever is contained in the scr portion is what I want returned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the latest watir-webdriver gem and you open HTML page that contains only

```
<iframe marginheight=0 marginwidth=0 frameborder=0 height=100 width=400 src="/website/authorisation.jsp?a=f556"></iframe>
```

you can get the value of `src` attribute with

```
browser.frame.src
```

It will return `"file:///website/authorisation.jsp?a=f556"`.

Comment: Thanks! I also found  `srctext = @browser.frame(:id,"authorizationFrame").attribute_value("src")`

Answer (score 0):

you can get iframe inner html by using javascript

Comment: I just need the scr tag to be returned in the ruby script I am using to test this website of mine. Is there no way of just accessing that?